# Android - Button with Header and additional text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, android-gridlayout

I want to create following view:

[image: My concept]

I have chosen a GridLayout and added 4 Buttons in it. Now every Button should have a header and an additional text (like my concept). What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I think you have worked in a custom listView. Similar way, try to custom a gridView, Hope this help: https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-gridview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html

Comment: Crate a custom view and set adapter to your gridview..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Here's my solution for this button

[image]

This is my `activity_main.xml` file content:

```
<!-- THIS IS YOUR SINGLE BUTTON-->
<!-- It has three parts-->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/item"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <!-- PART I.-->
    <!-- THIS IS YOUR BAR ON THE LEFT-->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

    <!-- PART II.-->
    <!-- THIS IS YOUR MIDDLE WITH TEXTS AND LINE-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="6"

        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- I thought that line has the same margin as strings-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <!-- ViewGroup with texts-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <!-- First is fitted with triangle - I think -->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:rotation="90.0"
                        android:src="@drawable/triangle"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Trainingsmodus"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Trainiere nach Themen sortiert"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- nothing more than single vertical line-->
            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#F1999999"></View>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- PART III.-->
    <!--LET'S SAY BUTTON ON THE RIGHT-->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=">"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_weight="6"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Create in your `drawable` folder inside your project directory `triangle.xml` and put into this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:toDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="-40%"
            android:pivotY="87%" >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle" >
                <solid
                    android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

That's only example how to make a button like above. Play with it, make yours and put into `GridView`. The picture in your post is good for landscape, not for portrait. Consider using both different orientation.

> NOTE: This example is lack of `android:id`. To use any adapter or set text programmatically you need add to every view `id`.

Hope it help

Comment: WOW! Thank you for the answer. Does it now mean that I need 4 xml-files (like item1.xml, item2.xml, item3.xml, item4.xml) and put them into a gridview as items?

Comment: that's one of possible ways. For beginning, it's enough. Then read about how to implement adapter using for example string array. Then you would have one view, the rest would be automatically generated from adapter with texts from array

Comment: Ok, I will try this. Now my last question: you set some fix values in the layout-file (e.g. width is 300dp or marginRight is 10dp). Can it be problematic on other screen resolutions? I want to achieve that it looks the same on all screens.

Comment: I can't answer this question directly. I tested on 4' screen size Samsung device. On 5's would be much more space on the right. On 6's and bigger you would rather use two column layout. Only I can say that with layout you would have much more fun, than you expect